# Where does arm ds-5 streamline data come from?

Tags: arm, ds-5, streamline

Streamline is a good tool to analyse system status, but where does the data come from. The AN shows that we do not need a specific hardware like JTAG to gather the data. Is it the same as systrace or something like that. How much overhead does the profiling mechanism cause?

Answer (score 1):

Streamline gets its data from the Gator driver you build for the target, which uses the kernel's own perf and tracing subsystems. The performance data comes from the monitors built into the hardware so the overhead for basic profiling should be relatively small. I haven't yet used it myself though, so I can't say for certain how much.

Answer (score 0):

Overhead from streamline is less than < 5% as per http://ds.arm.com/ds-5/optimize/streamline-faq/ and can be reduced, if desired, through Streamline settings, again mentioned in the FAQ.